# Campo calculado de fechas en el modelo con ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Buen día

Necesito calcular en el modelo un campo llamado "Dias" el cual se obtiene con la resta de una fecha de entrada y una fecha de salida. el campo lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera pero me mando error, la pregunta es ¿Cuál es la forma correcta para calcular los días transcurridos entre 2 fechas desde un campo calculado en el modelo?

El campo en modelo esta de la siguiente manera (Pero lo tengo con error):

```
public int Dias
    {
        get
        {
            return  Convert.ToInt32(EntryTime.Value.Date - ExitTime.Value.Date);
        }
    }
```

el error que me envio es: "No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.TimeSpan' al tipo 'System.IConvertible'".

Actualmente estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC  de visual studio 2019

saludos y gracias por el apoyo

Answer (score 0):

Esta operación de resta de fechas, devuelve un objeto [TimeSpan](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netcore-3.1), que representa un intervalo de tiempo.

Este objeto (`TimeSpan`) tiene entre su lista de propiedades unas cuyo nombre comienza por `Total...` y todas devuelven un número (`double`) que representa la cantidad de tiempo transcurrido en la unidad correspondiente (`TotalMinutes`, `TotalSeconds`, etc).

En tu caso, la cantidad de días la obtienes de la siguiente manera:

```
return Convert.ToInt32((ExitTime.Value.Date - EntryTime.Value.Date).TotalDays);
```

Ten en cuenta lo siguiente:

- La resta debe ser la fecha mayor menos la fecha menor, y eleboré el ejemplo por el significado de los nombres de las propiedades.
- La conversión `ToInt32` es porque el resultado en `TotalDays` puede contener decimales.

**Actualización**

Para obtener el resultado planteado en la pregunta complementaria que haces en los comentarios, debes cambiar el tipo de datos a la propiedad porque ahora la respuesta será un `string` y puedes utilizar [formatos personalizados](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings)

Por ejemplo:

```
public string Dias
{
    get
    {
        var duracion = ExitTime.Value.Date - EntryTime.Value.Date;
        return duracion.ToString(@"d' Dias 'h' horas 'm' minutos 's' segundos'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo, si funciona pero solo me da los dias, pero si yo quiero que me de el tiempo? transcurrido en dias, horas, minutos y segundos como lo hago?, es decir si yo tengo EntryTime='01/01/2020 08:50:20' y el ExitTime='01/01/2020 09:54:25' me deberìa de decir que han transcurrido: 0 dias, 1 hora, 4 minutos, 5 segundos..... como lo hago? te agradezco mucho todo el apoyo. gracias

Comment: Gracias por responder nuevamente Pablo. si me lo agrupa todo pero solo toma en cuanta los dias, es decir me pone lo siguiente, por ejemplo con estas 2 fechas EntryTime='01/01/2020 08:50:20' y el ExitTime='02/01/2020 09:54:25', me debería de poner: 1 dias 1 horas 4 minutos 5 segundos; y me pone 1 dias 0 horas  0 minutos 0 segundos

Comment: Si consideras que mi respuesta es la adecuada para tu requerimiento, considera marcarla como aceptada.